# Fix Modal Problems In Javascript and Css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I fix the body scrollbar problem, However, I assign the modal style to `padding-left: 17px`; but it just hides the modal scrollbar. How to hide the body scrollbar when the modal is active (like bootstrap)

Note:
When I active the modal (I can assign body `overflow: hidden`) and when I remove the active class from the modal (I can assign body `overflow: scroll`) ---> is it good?

---

My code :

```js
document.getElementById('modal-btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.querySelector('.modal').classList.add('active');
 // document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
});

document.getElementById('modal-hide').addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.querySelector('.modal').classList.remove('active');
 // document.body.style.overflow = 'scroll';
})
```

```css
.modal{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999999999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  overflow-y: auto;
  
  display: none;
  padding-left: 17px;
}
.modal.active{
  display: block;
}

.modal-content{
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
}

body{
  background-color: #f4f8ff;
    font-family: segoe ui;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.wp{
  width: 90%;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#modal-btn{
  padding: .25rem 1.25rem;
  font-family: segoe ui;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  cursor: pointer;
}


@media(max-width: 442px){
  .modal-content{
    width: 98%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wp">
  <div class="title">
  I am fine
</div>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel ipsa hic recusandae dolor. Cumque, ea. Fugiat ratione laudantium blanditiis dolore expedita? Adipisci inventore saepe minus quisquam natus officiis enim! Quia in explicabo aliquid illo voluptate nam laboriosam ad minus voluptas, repellendus provident. Temporibus voluptatum ut quia cum possimus inventore ratione?</p>
  
  <button id="modal-btn">
    Open Modal
  </button>
</div>

<div class="wp">
  <div class="title">
  I am fine
</div>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel ipsa hic recusandae dolor. Cumque, ea. Fugiat ratione laudantium blanditiis dolore expedita? Adipisci inventore saepe minus quisquam natus officiis enim! Quia in explicabo aliquid illo voluptate nam laboriosam ad minus voluptas, repellendus provident. Temporibus voluptatum ut quia cum possimus inventore ratione?</p>

</div>


<!-- Main Modal -->

<div class="modal">
   <div class="modal-content">
      I am the content
       <button id="modal-hide">
    Close Modal
  </button>
     
     <p>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus, fugit quo? Illo saepe magni molestias, accusantium molestiae, similique quibusdam officia fuga id adipisci suscipit architecto, omnis quo cum labore fugiat. Facere vel nulla blanditiis, voluptatem animi debitis, asperiores alias error sed tempora cum, architecto quia cumque distinctio sit ab nemo minima eveniet esse possimus deleniti omnis? Modi unde repellat quasi reiciendis suscipit corporis explicabo! Quaerat eveniet, ad iusto commodi officia ea quae dolor, quia architecto quibusdam voluptate autem vero. Eaque quasi temporibus recusandae. Quasi assumenda vero in odio sit neque modi deleniti quaerat laborum. Reiciendis dicta sunt laborum assumenda aliquid cumque sint recusandae temporibus itaque nisi, velit magnam officia inventore, id laboriosam! Aliquam expedita voluptate vel neque aspernatur obcaecati minus, tempora laudantium illum, eveniet totam eum incidunt. Quo consectetur dolorum, aliquid quas dicta quasi nisi soluta eaque earum nostrum exercitationem possimus tempore quisquam distinctio ducimus deleniti modi consequatur quod obcaecati maxime rem. Totam quos nisi natus laudantium nobis culpa fugit aspernatur quis voluptatum consequuntur perferendis incidunt fugiat alias quaerat architecto deserunt at, consequatur dolorum sequi sed, fuga quia! Officia dignissimos non id quam quibusdam ipsam cupiditate laborum blanditiis placeat minus cumque, harum expedita accusantium eligendi quo similique debitis fugiat eius natus? Placeat quis consectetur hic natus quam veritatis earum ipsam minima dolorem molestiae nemo fuga exercitationem vero repudiandae facere delectus autem iste at saepe sapiente, veniam doloremque! Error dolor dolorem cupiditate ab qui doloribus sapiente, cum eaque consectetur debitis aliquid maiores perspiciatis dignissimos officia ea possimus molestias? Earum rerum reiciendis possimus amet, voluptas qui minima velit veniam at consequuntur optio iusto repellat eveniet placeat autem ea, ipsam sunt ab commodi quos maiores. Ad a voluptatem quasi in molestiae expedita dolorem rerum eius id dignissimos neque sunt officia magnam et repellat suscipit, soluta fuga temporibus porro ab omnis nesciunt! Deleniti itaque quae, accusamus reprehenderit minus repellendus cupiditate nihil earum in, dolorem illum nobis excepturi velit ipsam modi dolores praesentium? Necessitatibus doloribus animi aut quos provident iusto reiciendis, asperiores corrupti voluptatem ipsa veniam libero ullam illo iure rem harum laborum porro at, neque, cum maxime tempora? Deleniti cupiditate omnis nesciunt error asperiores delectus quo architecto dolorem ut nostrum. Dolorem blanditiis quos est delectus quo soluta illo officiis, eum rem ad minus corporis optio minima cumque voluptates maiores ipsa quas! At numquam tempora explicabo soluta. Natus perferendis cumque fuga iusto nostrum porro nihil exercitationem incidunt suscipit voluptatum vero, rem molestias, commodi sit, corporis animi aliquid aperiam quam. Blanditiis, minima necessitatibus. Maxime, optio officiis quia commodi consectetur dignissimos omnis accusantium, nesciunt reiciendis illum voluptates id aspernatur officia suscipit, numquam earum recusandae voluptas voluptate eum illo nemo. Ea ipsam laboriosam similique veniam nesciunt labore esse laborum nulla. Laboriosam pariatur ex ipsa assumenda ad soluta alias, explicabo id accusamus nulla non reprehenderit perspiciatis quas nisi. Unde ad voluptatem quis, quo repellendus odit sint tempore non ex, similique architecto dolor. Eius quaerat enim accusamus nobis animi dignissimos earum eaque atque culpa optio esse iusto iure adipisci, deleniti qui voluptate. Dolor velit possimus placeat a quidem commodi quod?
     </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could continue using your approach of manipulating the classes. Simply define a class with `overflow: hidden` and add that class to the `body` element. Once you close the modal remove that class from the `body` element.

```js
document.getElementById('modal-btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.querySelector('.modal').classList.add('active');  document.querySelector('body').classList.add('modal-active');
});

document.getElementById('modal-hide').addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.querySelector('.modal').classList.remove('active');
 document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('modal-active');
})
```

```css
.modal{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999999999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  overflow-y: auto;
  
  display: none;
  padding-left: 17px;
}
.modal.active{
  display: block;
}

.modal-content{
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
}

body{
  background-color: #f4f8ff;
    font-family: segoe ui;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.wp{
  width: 90%;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#modal-btn{
  padding: .25rem 1.25rem;
  font-family: segoe ui;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  cursor: pointer;
}


@media(max-width: 442px){
  .modal-content{
    width: 98%;
  }
}

.modal-active {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wp">
  <div class="title">
  I am fine
</div>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel ipsa hic recusandae dolor. Cumque, ea. Fugiat ratione laudantium blanditiis dolore expedita? Adipisci inventore saepe minus quisquam natus officiis enim! Quia in explicabo aliquid illo voluptate nam laboriosam ad minus voluptas, repellendus provident. Temporibus voluptatum ut quia cum possimus inventore ratione?</p>
  
  <button id="modal-btn">
    Open Modal
  </button>
</div>

<div class="wp">
  <div class="title">
  I am fine
</div>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel ipsa hic recusandae dolor. Cumque, ea. Fugiat ratione laudantium blanditiis dolore expedita? Adipisci inventore saepe minus quisquam natus officiis enim! Quia in explicabo aliquid illo voluptate nam laboriosam ad minus voluptas, repellendus provident. Temporibus voluptatum ut quia cum possimus inventore ratione?</p>

</div>


<!-- Main Modal -->

<div class="modal">
   <div class="modal-content">
      I am the content
       <button id="modal-hide">
    Close Modal
  </button>
     
     <p>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus, fugit quo? Illo saepe magni molestias, accusantium molestiae, similique quibusdam officia fuga id adipisci suscipit architecto, omnis quo cum labore fugiat. Facere vel nulla blanditiis, voluptatem animi debitis, asperiores alias error sed tempora cum, architecto quia cumque distinctio sit ab nemo minima eveniet esse possimus deleniti omnis? Modi unde repellat quasi reiciendis suscipit corporis explicabo! Quaerat eveniet, ad iusto commodi officia ea quae dolor, quia architecto quibusdam voluptate autem vero. Eaque quasi temporibus recusandae. Quasi assumenda vero in odio sit neque modi deleniti quaerat laborum. Reiciendis dicta sunt laborum assumenda aliquid cumque sint recusandae temporibus itaque nisi, velit magnam officia inventore, id laboriosam! Aliquam expedita voluptate vel neque aspernatur obcaecati minus, tempora laudantium illum, eveniet totam eum incidunt. Quo consectetur dolorum, aliquid quas dicta quasi nisi soluta eaque earum nostrum exercitationem possimus tempore quisquam distinctio ducimus deleniti modi consequatur quod obcaecati maxime rem. Totam quos nisi natus laudantium nobis culpa fugit aspernatur quis voluptatum consequuntur perferendis incidunt fugiat alias quaerat architecto deserunt at, consequatur dolorum sequi sed, fuga quia! Officia dignissimos non id quam quibusdam ipsam cupiditate laborum blanditiis placeat minus cumque, harum expedita accusantium eligendi quo similique debitis fugiat eius natus? Placeat quis consectetur hic natus quam veritatis earum ipsam minima dolorem molestiae nemo fuga exercitationem vero repudiandae facere delectus autem iste at saepe sapiente, veniam doloremque! Error dolor dolorem cupiditate ab qui doloribus sapiente, cum eaque consectetur debitis aliquid maiores perspiciatis dignissimos officia ea possimus molestias? Earum rerum reiciendis possimus amet, voluptas qui minima velit veniam at consequuntur optio iusto repellat eveniet placeat autem ea, ipsam sunt ab commodi quos maiores. Ad a voluptatem quasi in molestiae expedita dolorem rerum eius id dignissimos neque sunt officia magnam et repellat suscipit, soluta fuga temporibus porro ab omnis nesciunt! Deleniti itaque quae, accusamus reprehenderit minus repellendus cupiditate nihil earum in, dolorem illum nobis excepturi velit ipsam modi dolores praesentium? Necessitatibus doloribus animi aut quos provident iusto reiciendis, asperiores corrupti voluptatem ipsa veniam libero ullam illo iure rem harum laborum porro at, neque, cum maxime tempora? Deleniti cupiditate omnis nesciunt error asperiores delectus quo architecto dolorem ut nostrum. Dolorem blanditiis quos est delectus quo soluta illo officiis, eum rem ad minus corporis optio minima cumque voluptates maiores ipsa quas! At numquam tempora explicabo soluta. Natus perferendis cumque fuga iusto nostrum porro nihil exercitationem incidunt suscipit voluptatum vero, rem molestias, commodi sit, corporis animi aliquid aperiam quam. Blanditiis, minima necessitatibus. Maxime, optio officiis quia commodi consectetur dignissimos omnis accusantium, nesciunt reiciendis illum voluptates id aspernatur officia suscipit, numquam earum recusandae voluptas voluptate eum illo nemo. Ea ipsam laboriosam similique veniam nesciunt labore esse laborum nulla. Laboriosam pariatur ex ipsa assumenda ad soluta alias, explicabo id accusamus nulla non reprehenderit perspiciatis quas nisi. Unde ad voluptatem quis, quo repellendus odit sint tempore non ex, similique architecto dolor. Eius quaerat enim accusamus nobis animi dignissimos earum eaque atque culpa optio esse iusto iure adipisci, deleniti qui voluptate. Dolor velit possimus placeat a quidem commodi quod?
     </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks (Bootstrap do the same things [modal-open])